# How to execute a flag after uncollapsing/clicking a (block) item?

Tags: routes, blocks, ajax, flags

I have this code working as a dropdown menu block that shows user's notifications, with a notification count item to its right:

```
<div class=notiwrapper>
<?php
global $user;

//We get the user's "notifications" field value and if it's greater than 0 show the counter
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
 if ($user_fields->field_notifications['und']['0']['value'] > 0) {
 $customfield = $user_fields->field_notifications['und']['0']['value'];}
 else
 {$customfield = '';}
 $text = 'Activity '.'<div class=blob>'.$customfield.'</div>';

 //here we print the block menu content (message's activity)
 $block = module_invoke('views','block_view','user_activity-block_1');
 $blocko= render($block);
 $output = '<div class="contento">'.$blocko.'</div>';
 $options = array('handle' => $text, 'content' => $output, 'collapsed' => TRUE);
 echo theme('ctools_collapsible',$options);
?>
</div>
```

Then I have a flag that sets the user's notifications field value to "0":

```
<?php print flag_create_link('unmark_notifications', $user->uid); ?>
```

The thing is that you have to click it separately to remove the notifications counter, but what I need is when I uncollapse the menu to execute the unmark_notifications flag too.

How can this be done?

Comment: You should be able to hook into the click on your menu uncollapse via jQuery to then click on the flag as well.  Check out https://drupal.org/node/336122 for more info on the Flag JS API that you might be able to hook into as well.

Comment: @Jimajamma The link shows how to do something after an item is flagged/unflagged, but I need the opposite :/ Anyway I found that I can execute the flag directly with: <?php
global $user;
$flag = flag_get_flag('unmark_notifications');
$flag->flag('flag', $user->uid);
?>..still don't know how to execute both..is it possible with an ajax callback?

Comment: You *should* be able to do all of this from the client.  To expound a bit, with javascript/jQuery, you can listen on whenever you click on the fieldset, eg, to open/uncollapse it.  So, with that in place you can also have your javascript programatically click on the flag link on the page and then bubble on past and open up the fieldset via ctools' js.  My original thought was to use the Flag JS API to then clear the count of user notifications to 0, but I guess that could be done in this routine as well.

Comment: @Jimajamma I have finally found a way. with this bit of jQuery I'm able to click the flag and the menu at the same time.

Comment: @Jimajamma this -->    (function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.scriptjs =  {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
    
    $('.activity_link').click(function() {
    $('.activity_menu').toggle();
    $('.blob').fadeOut('normal');
    $('.flag-unmark-notifications .flag-action').click();
    $('.flag-unmark-notifications .unflag-action').click();
});




    }
  };
})(jQuery);

Comment: @Jimajamma and this the html -->   <div id=container>
<a href="#" class="activity_link">Activity</a>
<?php
global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$user_notifications = $user_fields->field_notifications['und']['0']['value'];
if ($user_notifications > 0) {
echo '<div class=blob>'.$user_notifications.'</div>';
echo '<div style=display:none>'.flag_create_link('unmark_notifications', $user->uid).'</div>';}?></div>
<div class=activity_menu style=display:none>
<?php $invoke=module_invoke('views','block_view','user_activity-block_1');
$menu_block=render($invoke);
echo $menu_block;?></div>

Comment: Still trying to find a way to update the counter dinamically (without refreshing the page)..

Comment: You could use jQuery to set the .text() or .html() of the div it is in to whatever you want within your click() function above.